# How do I structure a SELECT query for the following

Tags: search, mysql, tags

Hoping that someone here will be able to provide some mysql advice...

I am working on a categorical searchtag system.  I have tables like the following:

```
EXERCISES
    exerciseID
    exerciseTitle

SEARCHTAGS
    searchtagID
    parentID ( -> searchtagID)
    searchtag

EXERCISESEARCHTAGS
    exerciseID (Foreign key -> EXERCISES)
    searchtagID (Foreign key -> SEARCHTAGS)
```

Searchtags can be arranged in an arbitrarily deep tree.  So for example I might have a tree of searchtags that looks like this...

```
Body Parts
    Head
    Neck
    Arm
        Shoulder
        Elbow
    Leg
        Hip
        Knee
Muscles
    Pecs
    Biceps
    Triceps
```

Now...

I want to select all of the searchtags in ONE branch of the tree that reference at least ONE record in the subset of records referenced by a SINGLE searchtag in a DIFFERENT branch of the tree.

For example, let's say the searchtag "Arm" points to a subset of exercises.  If any of the exercises in that subset are also referenced by searchtags from the "Muscles" branch of SEARCHTAGS, I would like to select for them.  So my query could potentially return "Biceps," "Triceps".

Two questions:

1) What would the SELECT query for something like this look like?  (If such a thing is even possible without creating a lot of slow down.  I'm not sure where to start...)

2) Is there anything I should do to tweak my datastructure to ensure this query will continue to run fast - even as the tables get big?

Thanks in advance for your help, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, use [modified preorder tree traversal](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/2), also known as the [nested set model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).  It requires two fields (left and right) instead of one (parent id), and makes certain operations harder, but makes selecting whole branches much easier.

Answer (score 1):

An idea: consider using a cache table that saves all ancestor relationships in your searchtags:

```
CREATE TABLE SEARCHTAGRELATIONS (
    parentID INT,
    descendantID INT
);
```

Also include the tag itself as parent and descendant (so, for searchtag with id 1, the relations table includes a row with (1,1).

That way, you get rid of the parent/descendant relationships and can join a flat table. Assuming "Muscles" has the ID 5,

```
SELECT descendantID FROM SEARCHTAGRELATIONS WHERE parentID=5
```

returns all searchtags contained in muscles.